# mocking 2 classes from 2 different files

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, python-3.7

I have an example of class mocking :

**worker.py**

```
import os

class Helper:

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def get_folder(self):
        base_path = os.getcwd()
        return os.path.join(base_path, self.path)

    def get_path(self):
        return self.path


class Worker:

    def __init__(self):
        self.helper = Helper('db')

    def work(self):
        path = self.helper.get_path()
        print(f'Working on {path}')
        return path
```

And a test file : **test_worker.py**

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock

from worker import Worker, Helper

class TestWorkerModule(TestCase):

    def test_patching_class(self):
        with mock.patch('worker.Helper') as MockHelper:
            MockHelper.return_value.get_path.return_value = 'testing'
            worker = Worker()
            self.assertEqual(worker.work(), 'testing')
```

The test returns ok as long as the 2 classes are in the same file. Separating them into 2 files worker_1.py for class Helper and worker_2.py for class Worker, the test fails with :

```
AssertionError: 'db' != 'testing'
```

Why ? And how can I correct this behaviour ?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question title into something that actually has meaning. Your question should be descriptive enough to be of use to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results looking for a solution to their problem. Your current title does not provide any meaningful information. It's clearly a question or it wouldn't be here, it's clearly related to mocking because you added that tag, and the remaining words don't provide anything useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say we have two files, worker.py and helper.py

worker.py:

```
from helper import Helper

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.helper = Helper('db')

    def work(self):
        path = self.helper.get_path()
        print('Working on {path}')
        return path
```

helper.py:

```
import os

class Helper:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def get_folder(self):
        base_path = os.getcwd()
        return os.path.join(base_path, self.path)

    def get_path(self):
        return self.path
```

What you did here is to import Helper class into worker module,
so when you trying to do that at your test_worker.py:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock

from worker import Worker

class TestWorkerModule(TestCase):
    def test_patching_class(self):
        with mock.patch('helper.Helper') as MockHelper:
            MockHelper.return_value.get_path.return_value = 'testing'
            worker = Worker()
            self.assertEqual(worker.work(), 'testing')
```

result:

```
AssertionError: 'db' != 'testing'
- db
+ testing
```

you are patching the Helper class in helper.py module,
but you already imported the Helper class into worker module, because of that you need to patch the Helper class in worker module, for example:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock

from worker import Worker

class TestWorkerModule(TestCase):
    def test_patching_class(self):
        with mock.patch('worker.Helper') as MockHelper:
            MockHelper.return_value.get_path.return_value = 'testing'
            worker = Worker()
            self.assertEqual(worker.work(), 'testing')
```

result:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Another way to make it work for general use cases (lets say you want to patch Helper class in all modules that use it), it is to change worker.py to that:

```
import helper

class Worker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.helper = helper.Helper('db')

    def work(self):
        path = self.helper.get_path()
        print('Working on {path}')
        return path
```

here you are importing helper module, and use Helper class under helper module,
so now your test.py should seem like that:

```
from unittest import TestCase, mock

from worker import Worker

class TestWorkerModule(TestCase):
    def test_patching_class(self):
        with mock.patch('helper.Helper') as MockHelper:
            MockHelper.return_value.get_path.return_value = 'testing'
            worker = Worker()
            self.assertEqual(worker.work(), 'testing')
```

result:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Thats worked because instead of importing the Helper class into worker module, we have imported the helper module, so patching "helper.Helper" will now really work correctly.